# Build count down timer with pause button in android

Tags: android

I tried to build a contdown timer with pause button, for making timer to pause I tried to build a new timer with the left time, below is my code, but the problem is that it works just once, after pressing pause button for twice, old timer does not get cancel and wotks with the new one, what can I do?

```
pauseB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!timerHasPaused) {
                startTime = (long) (temp * 1000);
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval); 
                timerHasPaused = true;
                pauseB.setText("Play");
        } else {
                PcountDownTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = false;
                pauseB.setText("Pause");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: plz paste MyCountDownTimer code

Comment: when you click on pause button you have to store the the counter value and when click resume then you have to take stored value as start point. every time you will click pause value will save and on click resume the value will be starting value.

Comment: show the `MyCountDownTimer` code. This is a good code of timer tool with pause option: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Timer/multitimer-android/com/cycleindex/multitimer/CountDownTimerWithPause.java.htm